# How can I create loop in if-else statement?

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, if-statement

I´m trying to create loop in if-else statement in WPF Application.I'd like to create an error counter that when it reaches 4 it ends the game.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Random prvni = new Random();
            Random druhy = new Random();
            int maxprvni = 10;
            int maxdruhy = 10;
            int prvnic = prvni.Next(1, maxprvni);
            int druhyc = druhy.Next(2, maxdruhy);
            int total = (prvnic + druhyc);
            prvnit.Text = prvnic.ToString();
            druhyt.Text = druhyc.ToString();
            vysledek.Text = total.ToString();
        }

        private void kontrola_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (vysledekhrac.Text == vysledek.Text)
            {
                hlaska.Text = "Správně";
            }
            else
            {
                int poch = new Int32();
                do
                {
                    hlaska.Text = "Špatně";                   
                    poch++;
                    pocetchyb.Text = poch.ToString();
                    
                } while (poch==4);
               
            }
        }
```

This code will ensure that it normally spells it wrong or right but does not add it to the total number of errors.

The application is only adding random number for the time being, but I would like to complete other numerical operations in the future but I will definitely ask the question some other time :D

Thank you for your any advice

Comment: With `== 4` it will run 0 or 1 times. More an if() than a loop.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes thats right. Thank you!

Comment: My mistake, it's a do-while. It will run 1 or 2 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use field containing the errors counter outside of the method. No loop needed.

```cs
// fields always automatically intialized with default value which is 0 for 'int'.
private int poch;

private void kontrola_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (vysledekhrac.Text == vysledek.Text)
    {
        hlaska.Text = "Správně";
    }
    else
    {
        hlaska.Text = "Špatně";
        poch++;
        pocetchyb.Text = poch.ToString();
        if (poch == 4)
        {
            // end game
        }
    }
}
```